# Danish keyboard and special characters on VirtualBox with Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, virtualbox, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I have an issue with the danish keyboard layout and special characters on a VirtualBox with Ubuntu Server installed

PC with MX Anywwhere wireless mouse and a Razer Blackwidow V3 Pro Keyb connected with USB cable, 104 keys according to specs
Host latest Windows 10
VM: VirtualBox version 7.0.12
Guest: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
All packages upgraded
Only console no "GUI"

Purpose was to experiment with Ubuntu and NET 8 before I order VPS hosting for a small project I like to go live with

Keyboard changed with the command
`sudo dkpg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`

Tried the different generic keyboard configurations
Chose AltGr as compose key?

Everything works fine except extended characters like pipe "|" or sqare brackets
No extended characters gives input on the console

Bottom keys from left to right on the keyboard
Ctrl, Win, Alt, Space, Alt, Fn, Local Menu, Ctrl

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>AltGr</kbd> as compose key is a bad choice, since <kbd>AltGr</kbd> is used by default to access 3:rd and 4:th level symbols. The characters you mentioned are such symbols. So pick some other key as the compose key, and you will probably notice a difference.

Comment: Thanks, tried another key as the compose key to avoid conflicts, but no luch. I will use alt-### to get the characters I need. Afterall it is just an experiment (eg alt-124 for the pipe character)

Answer (score 0):

I installed Virtualbox Essentials to mount a shared folder
Special characters is working now, maybe not so weird?

Keyboard Configuration:

- Generic 104 with L-shaped Enter key
- Danish -> Danish (Windows)
- Right Alt (AltGr)
- Compose key -> Meu key